# Error in literal type checking by the mypy tool

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, type-narrowing

I integrated `mypy` into my code, but there is error in type checking of the literal:

```
error: Item "None" of "Optional[Type[Temp]]" has no attribute "pankaj"  [union-attr]
```

It is treating `b` as always `Optional[Type[Temp]]`. When `a` is True, then `b` should not be `Optional`, otherwise `b` is `Optional`. However, `mypy` gives the same error in both branches:

```py
class Temp:
    @staticmethod
    def pankaj():
        print("pankaj")

def accepts_only_int(x: int) -> Union[tuple[Literal[True],Type[Temp]],tuple[Literal[False],Optional[Type[Temp]]]]:
    return (False,Temp)

a, b=accepts_only_int(6)

if a:
    print(b.pankaj())
else:
    print(a,b.pankaj())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mypy` cannot track dependencies of several variables, it's an implementation limitation. To work this around, do not unpack `accepts_only_int` - assign it to one variable `a` and test `if a[0]`. Then you're not referring to several variables, but narrow a tuple by it's item type from union. You can unpack in conditional branches later:

```py
from typing import Literal

class Temp:
    @staticmethod
    def pankaj() -> None:
        print("pankaj")

def accepts_only_int(x: int) -> tuple[Literal[True], type[Temp]] | tuple[Literal[False], type[Temp] | None]:
    return (False, Temp)

a = accepts_only_int(6)

if a[0]:
    _, temp = a
    print(temp.pankaj())
else:
    print(a[0], a[1].pankaj())  # E: Item "None" of "Optional[Type[Temp]]" has no attribute "pankaj"  [union-attr]
```

This has only one `mypy` error, as expected. Here's [a playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=d4c69702b8ecdcd47bdc12d6a62bd69a).